# Algorithm for 3-object matching

Tags: algorithms, graphs, time-complexity

I believe that in the general case stable matching for 3 members rather than 2 is NP-Complete, but I wonder if in my case there's something that I am missing that could have reasonable time complexity.

The specific purpose of the program I am trying to write is to take an arbitrary number of objects and split them into groups of 3. Hypothetically, each object has a color (let's say right now there's 10 possible colors).

The part of this group creation that allows something of a "preference list" of other members is both having group members of different colors and having been grouped with them in the past as little times as possible.

Everything I have come up with either has horrendous time complexity or has the chance of failing (missing possible groupings). If anyone has done anything like this before I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE! Can you give a more precise statement of the algorithmic task?  What are the inputs?  What is the desired output?  Presumably, you want to find a grouping that satisfies some condition.  What is that condition?  I don't understand the sentence "The part of this..." -- that is too vague for me.  We'll probably need to understand what problem you are trying to solve before we can tell whether it is NP-complete or not.

Comment: Not clear to me.  Are there limits to the size of each group?

Comment: To be more clear, the size of each group should be 3. Ideally the number of objects would be a multiple of three.

As for the inputs, there would be a list of objects the program loads, all of which contain a unique identifier, a color, and a list of the other objects it's already been grouped with in past runs.

The output should the least conflicted groupings with no repeat objects along with the "conflicts" it contains. A conflict being a grouping with >1 of the same color object or a grouping with objects that have been grouped in the past.

Comment: I believe it makes sense to imagine the output as a list of sports teams (of size 3) for a tournament. While there are technically approximately 10 specializations/positions possible, it would make for the best team if it's members weren't the same specialization/position. Also imagine these players should be socialized, so every time a tournament is made players being on a team with past teammates should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for a polynomial-time approximation algorithm for the [3-dimensional matching problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-dimensional_matching) (which is, as you noted, NP-complete - the decision problem is one of Karp's 21 NP-complete problems).

In 2014, [Ostrovsky and Rosenbaum proved that 3D matching is APX-complete](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.1130.pdf). This implies the existence of an efficient algorithm that produces a result within a "fixed multiplicative factor of the optimal answer" - in their case, $4/9$.